# Cygwin throws randomly "permission denied" errors mostly or all related to the fork call

Tags: bash, find, cygwin, fork, windows-server-2012

Since a while, a script embedding a `find` loop command with a `-exec` argument started to fail on a couple of our client's servers with a `"Permission denied"` message.

To isolate the issue, I tried the line below:

```
find "/cygdrive/path/to/dir" some-filter-args -exec echo {} ';' -exec file {} ';'
```

After a while, the error message below occurs while `find` continues (this may occurs several times):

```
find : ‘echo’: Permission denied
```

It seems to be a very severe error, since it's related to the execution of `echo`. A `ls -l` check shows that `/bin/echo.exe` is owned the logged user with administrator privileges (and Cygwin is running as Administrator).

I tested another line, piping the `find` output to a `while` loop:

```
find "/cygdrive/path/to/dir" some-filter-args | while read a ; do wc –l "$a" ; done
```

An error occurs, with a different yet related message:

```
dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'Path\To\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe', errno 13
-bash: fork: Permission denied
```

The script itself is basically a find loop executing grep invoking a piped command line:

```
find "/cygdrive/path/to/dir" some-filter-args \
     -exec grep -L 'text' '{}' ';' |
while read line ; do
  # [...]
  # At least the command below should perform a fork() call
  echo "some_stuff" | (>&2 tee -a "/logs/output.log")
  # [...]
done
```

The following error occurs:

```
      1 [main] bash 645 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'Path\To\Cygwin\bin\find.exe', errno 13
/cygdrive/path/to/a/script/w/pipe: fork: Permission denied
      1 [main] bash 23354 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'Path\To\Cygwin\bin\find.exe', errno 13

/cygdrive/path/to/a/script/w/pipe: fork: Permission denied
find: ‘grep’ terminated by signal 13
      1 [main] find 644 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'Path\To\Cygwin\bin\find.exe', errno 13
find: cannot fork: Permission denied
```

I've the feeling that something prevents a process to perform a fork call beyond a limit. Symantec End Point protection is installed on these servers.

What can I check on these servers to figure out what causes this issue?

**Configuration details:**

- **Cygwin** - Setup version 2.901 (64 bit)
- **bash** 4.4.12-3
- **findutils** 4.6.0-1
- **grep** 3.0-2

Comment: https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures

Comment: @JoshCooley, thanks. I already noticed this page. I admit I'm skeptical about a full rebase since we didn't installed new files. Anyway, I'll ask the client to try it, and I'll go also for a `bloda` detection activation.

Comment: BLODA is the most likely problem. Check the antivirus and try with disabling it to confirm the interference. Sometime excluding the Cygwin directories is enough but it is not 100% effective.

Comment: @matzeri, `export CYGWIN=detect_bloda` was tried, but not detection displayed in the Cygwin console. Where bloda detection should be printed?

Comment: Well, **`detect_bloda`** value is [obsolete](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html), since "No case of a BLODA found by this option has been reported in years".

Comment: First, try replacing `-exec echo {}` with `-print`. This may not fix the problem, so try splitting the command so find with the -print writes to a temporary file which you source or run as a script.

Comment: @DougHenderson, thank you, I splitted and redirected to a temporary file. Works like a charm. Then I ran the grep command inside a loop, `while read f ; do grep -L 'text' "$f"  < findtempfile > greptempfile` and get the same error since `findtempfile` contains thousands of lines, I don't know how to get ride of more `fork()` calls.

Comment: I have my c:/cygwin64/bin folder in win defender's exclusion list. Also the /usr/bin folder. One has files, other is a mount point within Cygwin. Hate to suggest this, but try putting a 1 second sleep inside the while loop, if all else fails.

Comment: @DougHenderson, I was thinking about the sleep thing indeed. Awul. :)

Comment: @DougHenderson, I guess [creating a hardlink directory](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html) `$ mkdir --mode=a=rwxt /var/run/cygfork` is not related at all to this issue?

Comment: Why are you not using the very latest packages from cygwin? You are way behind for Cygwin, and I am pretty sure there are some fork and pipe io patches in there.

Comment: @DougHenderson, we tried yesterday to install the newest packages. However, the noticeable difference came with creating the **`cygfork`** directory to allow Cygwin to copy binaries into it if `fork()` fails the first time ([link 1](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.api.fork), [link 2](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html#ov-hi-process)). Dadly, it still fails at a certain point. I'm working on some workarounds.